# How to read a textfile by x number of lines, but x is unknown?

Tags: python, io, text-files, newline

I have a file where they are segmented by "\n" and the number of lines per segment is unknown. A sample of the file looks like this:

```
800004
The London and North-Western's Euston Station was first, but at the eastern end of Euston Road the Great Northern constructed their King's Cross terminal. 
Initially the Midland Railway ran into King's Cross but a quarrel over access led them to construct next door to King's Cross their St Pancras terminal, which was topped by a statue of Britannia, a <tag "510285">calculated</> snook-cocking exercise because Britannia was the company emblem of the Midland's hated rival, the London and North-Western. 

800005
GROWTH in Malaysia's gross domestic product this year is expected to be 8.5 per cent.
Nearly two percentage points higher than the Treasury's estimate, Bank Negara, the central bank, reported yesterday. 
Last year's growth, <tag "510270">calculated</> by the bank, was 8.7 per cent, compared with 7.6 per cent by the Treasury.   

800006
He was a Catholic. 
When he visited the Pope, even then, he couldn't help <tag "510270">calculating</> the Pope's worldly riches (life-proprietor of the Sistine Chapel, landlord of the Vatican and contents &ellip. ).
```

Is there a simpler way of getting the segments from the textfile?

I've been doing it this way:

```
doc = []
segments = []
for line in open(trainfile):
    if line == "\n":
        doc.append(segments)
        segments = []
    else:
        segments.append(line.strip())

for i in doc:
    print i
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a generator function:

```
def per_section(it):
    section = []
    for line in it:
        if line.strip():
            section.append(line)
        else:
            yield ''.join(section)
            section = []
    # yield any remaining lines as a section too
    if section:
       yield ''.join(section)
```

This yields each section, separated by blank lines, as one string:

```
with open(sectionedfile, 'r') as inputfile:
    for section in per_section(inputfile):
        print section
```

Comment: I don't undetstand this 100% so I hope you'd be so kind as to explain it to me. Why are 2 yields necessary ? The first already yields the section. Then when the for loop is done we yield the last section again ?

Comment: i dont understand why do you need the 2nd `if section: yield  ''.join(section)` too

Comment: If your file ends without an empty line, the last section would be ignored. By testing if there are any lines left in `section` we make sure it is not forgotten and left out. If there *is* a blank line at the end of the file, `section` has been cleared and that last `if` statement will return `False`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like `itertools.groupby` would be your friend here:

```
for k,section in groupby(file,key=str.isspace):
    if k:
       for line in section:
           ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not huge then you can also use `str.split` and split at `'\n\n'`:

If the file is huge then use the method suggested by @Martijn Pieters

```
with open('abc') as f:
    data = f.read()
    segments = data.split('\n\n')
...     
for x in segments:
    print '--->',x
```

**output:**

```
---> 800004
The London and North-Western's Euston Station was first, but at the eastern end of Euston Road the Great Northern constructed their King's Cross terminal. 
Initially the Midland Railway ran into King's Cross but a quarrel over access led them to construct next door to King's Cross their St Pancras terminal, which was topped by a statue of Britannia, a <tag "510285">calculated</> snook-cocking exercise because Britannia was the company emblem of the Midland's hated rival, the London and North-Western. 
---> 800005
GROWTH in Malaysia's gross domestic product this year is expected to be 8.5 per cent.
Nearly two percentage points higher than the Treasury's estimate, Bank Negara, the central bank, reported yesterday. 
Last year's growth, <tag "510270">calculated</> by the bank, was 8.7 per cent, compared with 7.6 per cent by the Treasury.   
---> 800006
He was a Catholic. 
When he visited the Pope, even then, he couldn't help <tag "510270">calculating</> the Pope's worldly riches (life-proprietor of the Sistine Chapel, landlord of the Vatican and contents &ellip. ).
```